# Performance in SQL sentence containing ORDER BY, LIMIT and COUNT

Tags: sql, tags, count, sql-order-by

I've searched the way of improving this dangerous combination of functions in one SQL sentence...

To put you in a context, i have a table with several information about articles (article_id, author, ...) and another one containing the article_id with one tag_id. As an article is able to have several tags, that second table could have 2 rows with the same article_id and different tag_id.

In order to get a list of the 8 articles that have more tags in common with the one that i want (in this case the 1354) I have written the following query:

```
SELECT articles.article_id, articles.author, count(articles_tags.article_id) as times
FROM articles
INNER JOIN articles_tags ON (articles.article_id=articles_tags.article_id)
WHERE id_tag IN
    (SELECT article_id FROM articles_tags WHERE article_id=1354)
AND article_id <> 1354
GROUP BY article_id
ORDER BY times DESC
LIMIT 8
```

It is EXTREMELY slow... like 90 seconds for half million articles.

By deleting the "order by times" sentence, it works almost instantly, but if i do so, i won't get the most similar articles.

What can i do?

Thanks!!

Comment: `WHERE id_tag IN (SELECT article_id FROM articles_tags WHERE article_id=1354)` - is that correct? I mean `.. id_tag IN (SELECT article_id ..` seems like you try to find `id_tag`s by selecting `article_id`s. I may be wrong.

Comment: What SQL vendor is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a query on a sub-select is ALWAYS a time-killer... Also, as the query didn't really appear to be accurate, or missing, I am making an assumption that your articles_tags table has two columns... one for the actual article ID, and another for the tag_ID associated with it.

That said, I would pre-query just the TAG IDs for article 1354 (the on you are interested in).  Use that as a Cartesian join to the article tags again on the tag IDs being the same.  From that, you are grabbing the SECOND version of article tags alias and getting ITs article ID, and then the count that MATCH (via Join and not a left-join).  Apply the group by on the article ID as you had, And for grins, join to the articles table to get the author.

Now, note.  Some SQL engines require you to group by all non-aggregate fields, so you MAY have to either add the author to the group by (which will always be the same per article ID anyway), or change it to MAX( A.author ) as Author which would give the same results.

I would have an index on the (tag_id, article_id) so the tags are found from the "common" tags you are looking to find in common.  You could have one article with 10 tags, and another article with 10 completely different tags resulting in 0 in common.  This will prevent the other article from even appearing in the result set.

You STILL have the time associated with blowing through half-million articles as you described, which could be millions of actual tag entries.

```
select 
      AT2.article_id,
      A.Author,
      count(*) as Times
   from
      ( select ATG.id_tag
           from articles_tags ATG
           where ATG.Article_ID = 1354
           order by ATG.id_tag ) CommonTags
         JOIN articles_tags AT2
            on CommonTags.ID_Tag = AT2.ID_Tag
            AND AT2.Article_ID <> 1354
            JOIN articles A
               on AT2.Article_ID = A.Article_ID
   group by
      AT2.article_id
   order by
      Times DESC
   limit 8
```

Comment: i find your query very interesting, but actually only improved the time in a few seconds, using more than 1 minute to take the results.
will be maybe related with indexes?

Comment: The only OTHER element I would consider is for "similar", you required AT LEAST ONE of the "other" tags for a given article, and pre-query those articles that have the one article at a minimum, then continue rest of compare.  Is that possible to apply?  How many tags might be common to test with for a given article, and how many "tags" are available an article could be tagged with.  Do your tags have some sort of "weight" of importance that could be used in comparing "similar"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it should be possible to do this without any subqueries, and then a quicker query may result.

Here the article of interest is joined to its tags, and then further to other articles having these tags. Then the number of tags for each article is counted and ordered:

```
SELECT a2.article_id, a2.author, COUNT(t2.tag_id) AS times
FROM articles a1 
INNER JOIN articles_tags t1
ON t1.article_id = a1.article_id   -- find tags for staring article
INNER JOIN tags t2
ON t2.tag_id = t1.tag_id           -- find other instances of those tags
AND t2.articles_id <> t1.articles_id
INNER JOIN articles a2
ON a2.articles_id = t2.articles_id -- and the articles where they are used
WHERE a1.article_id = 1354
GROUP BY a2.article_id, a2.author  -- count common tags by articles
ORDER BY times DESC
LIMIT 8
```

If you know a lower bound on the number of tags in common (e.g. 3), inserting `HAVING times > 2` before `ORDER BY times DESC` could give a further speed improvement.